# What is the solution for this to capture the date in between the String using regex?

Tags: java, regex

Please can any one help me if I want to take the Date in between the String?

```
Print Date: 2011/12/23 (YYYY/MM/DD)
```

I just wanted to take the date over here and I need to convert the format to DD/MM/YYYY.

Comment: Instead of shouting, you could have edited your question and added the correct tag (which now DSM has done for you). If you had read the regex tag's FAQ, you'd have known this even before posting.

Comment: Hello, @SambasivareddyNeerugatti, welcome to StackOverflow!  Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and our community will be much more helpful, useful, and friendly!

Answer (score 1):

This code will do..if you are using C#

```
Regex readdate = new Regex(@"(?<Year>(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))/(?<Month>\d{1,2})/(?<Day>\d{1,2})");
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(readdate.Match("Print Date: 2011/12/23").ToString()));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

In perl:

```
$str = 'Print Date: 2011/12/23 (YYYY/MM/DD)';
$date = $str =~ s#^\D+(\d{4})/\d{}/\d{2}.*$#$3/$2/$1#;
```

Comment: @SambasivareddyNeerugatti: I don't know Java but, sure, it could be translated easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
public static String convertDateString(String s) {
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4})/(\\d{2})/(\\d{2})");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
  if (m.find()) {
    return m.group(3) + "/" + m.group(2) + "/" + m.group(1);
  }
  return null;
}
// ...
convertDateString("2011/12/23"); // => "23/12/2011"
```

Or, if you just want to do it "in-place", try this:

```
public static String convertDateString2(String s) {
  StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4})/(\\d{2})/(\\d{2})");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
  if (m.find()) {
    buf.append(s.substring(0, m.start(1)));
    buf.append(m.group(3)).append("/");
    buf.append(m.group(2)).append("/");
    buf.append(m.group(1)).append(s.substring(m.end(3)));
    return buf.toString();
  }
  return null;
}
// ...
convertDateString2("Print Date: 2011/12/23.");
// => "Print Date: 23/12/2011."
```

Comment: @SambasivareddyNeerugatti: feel free to upvote and/or accept this answer as the correct one by pressing the checkbox next to it.